# How can I change try catch exception to WebDriverWait

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to login and search records based on date selected from a calendar. I have used try catch exception after each step. I need to replace try catch with WebDriverWait. But the problem is that I have fields on the page which are getting identified by id or XPath. So I am not getting a way out how to implement WebDriverWait instead of try catch. Can anyone help me out? Below is my code structure with details.

```
public class Login {
    public static WebDriver driver;
    String username = "username";
    String password = "password";
    String baseurl = "http://mybusiness.com/login.aspx";


public class Details {  
    @Test(priority = 0)
    public void loginpage() {
        //WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\From H\\Selenium Package\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--incognito"));
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--test-type");
        options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
        capabilities.setCapability("chrome.binary","D:\\From H\\Selenium Package\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);


        driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get(baseurl);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000); // 1000 milliseconds is one second.
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.id("UserName"));
        username.sendKeys(username);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000); // 1000 milliseconds is one second.
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("Password"));
        password.sendKeys(password);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.id("ButtonClick"));
        button.click();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }

    // Selecting a date from date picker
    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void RecordSearch() {
        WebElement calendar = driver.findElement(By.id("CalendarId"));
        calendar.click();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000); // 1000 milliseconds is one second.
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

        WebElement month = driver.findElement(By.xpath("XPath"));
        month.click();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000); // 1000 milliseconds is one second.
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

        WebElement day = driver.findElement(By.xpath("XPath"));
        day.click();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000); // 1000 milliseconds is one second.
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

        WebElement submit = driver.findElement(By.id("Submit"));
        submit.click();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000); // 1000 milliseconds is one second.
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

    }

        driver.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple example would take your code

```
try
{
    Thread.sleep(10000); // 1000 milliseconds is one second.
}
catch (InterruptedException ex)
{
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.id("UserName"));
username.sendKeys(username);
```

and change it to

```
String username = "username123";
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); // 10 seconds
WebElement usernameField = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("UserName")));
usernameField.sendKeys(username);
```

Once you have defined `wait`, you can reuse it over and over and it will have the same attributes, e.g. 10 sec wait time.

```
String password = "abc123";
WebElement passwordField = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("Password")));
passwordField.sendKeys(password);
```

---

NOTE: I noticed that you were using `username.sendKeys(username);`. I'm assuming/hoping this isn't actual code since `.sendKeys()` takes a `String` and you have `username` defined as a `WebElement`. I fixed it in my code and named the two differently.

Comment: Sir. It seems like your solution has cleared my all confusions which i struggled this entire day. Yes, i misspelled username.sendKeys(username) instead of username.sendKeys(userName) and (passWord) for the sake of an example.

Comment: @JeffC...I am getting "Cannot instantiate class detailsPkg_user.DetailSearch" error. When i am defining "WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); // 10 seconds" under "public class Login".

Comment: @Arvind the error you are getting doesn't seem related to the line you are referencing. I would suggest that you start a new question with the details so you can be helped.

Answer (score 1):

I would have thought you'd be better off adding an implicit wait, e.g. once you've setup your driver object add the following line:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: i tried implicitlyWait ealier. But didn't worked out. That's y i turned for try catch.

Comment: When you say it wasn't working, what do you mean? Was it still not finding the element, how long did you set the wait for?

Comment: it didn't find element after login criteria. I set the time for 10 seconds

Answer (score 0):

If you explore little, you can find different types of `WebDriverWait`. One of the most common is `WebDriver.wait(timeinmilliseconds)`.

and for example, others are,

```
webDriver.waituntil (Expectedconditions)...

wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
        WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.className("sel"));
        String enabled = button.getText();
        return enabled.contains(city);
    }
});
```

or for example

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.id("froexample_username_txtbox")));
```

PS : `define private final WebDriverWait wait;`

It may be more useful if you are not sure about implict timewait value.(be being specific about events and results)

Comment: Implicit didn't worked out for me as i tried it at the beginning. Let me check with this method

Answer (score 0):

There is `WebDriverWait` functionality in selenium, you can set explicit wait. You are using selenium webdriver, then it is far better to use `WebDriverWait` for waiting purpose to element. follow below code

```
protected WebElement waitForPresent(final String locator, long timeout) {
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);
  WebElement ele = null;
  try {
       ele = wait.until(ExpectedConditions
            .presenceOfElementLocated(locator));
  } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
 }
 return ele;
}

protected WebElement waitForNotPresent(final String locator, long timeout) {
    timeout = timeout * 1000;
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    WebElement ele = null;
    while ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) < timeout) {
        try {
            ele = findElement(locator);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return ele;
}
```

Whenever you require wait for element present, call waitForPresent method with expected parameters.

Comment: presenceOfElementLocatedBy is not an appropriate type and even visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy as well.

Comment: Can you suggest me where you are facing issue? I gave generalize method which can access by method with parameters. In my case it is working properly.